# How to change chrome proxy via command line windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, netsh

I have tried to update the settings with:

`netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="127.0.0.1:8080" bypass-list=""`

also tried:

`netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="http=127.0.0.1:8080" bypass-list=""`

But no effect, the traffic just don't go through the proxy.

I have also used this:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d 127.0.0.2:8080 /f
```

but the problem is I can't override the settings, once I pick one proxy, even though I disable the proxy with:

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

the settings stay and I have to go to Internet Explorer > Internet Options > Connection > Lan Settings to change it, and the command doesn't work anymore, just the first time.

Comment: This can be used to set a proxy sever for Google Chrome via cmd? Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong,

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

does the trick, the thing is, it is necesary to restart the brower to apply the changes.